# Find the position of X and Y depending on specific color php imagecolorat()

Tags: php, image

I am having a problem with php imagecolorat. actually what I want is to find the X and Y position of the black rectangle of top left corner.
but when i am running the code there is nothing on the screen :3

[image link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwK-syg5gJTob1RIa2J1SXdtVW8/view?usp=sharing)

```
 $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("omr.jpg");


    $rgb = imagecolorat( $im , 41 , 5);
    $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xff;
    $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b = $rgb & 0xFF;


 function check_rotation ($y)

    {
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg("omr.jpg");

    $rgb = imagecolorat( $im , 41 , $y);
    $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xff;
    $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $b = $rgb & 0xFF;


    };

for($y=6 ;$r<125 && $g<125 && $b<125; $y++ )
        {

        check_rotation ($y); 
        echo "$y <br>";
        $y=$y1;
        echo"$y1";
        }
```

N.B. I know about jquery page x and y but it has no use to me.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You aren't exporting r, g and b from check_rotation, so they never change. And I think it's best if you write (($r < 125) && ($g < 125) && ($b < 125)), and add a sanity limit to the $y, or you might get an infinite loop out of that for().

Comment: Thanks
but can you please give me the working code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the top-left corner of the black pixel like this:

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("omr.jpg");
for($x=0;$x<100;$x++){
   for($y=0;$y<100;$y++){
      $rgb = imagecolorat($im,$x,$y);
      $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
      $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
      $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
      if($r<128 && $g<128 && $b<128){
         printf("%d,%d: %d,%d,%d\n",$x,$y,$r,$g,$b);
         exit;
      }
   }
}
```

**Output:**

```
30,53: 82,78,75
```

You may want to think about thresholdinng your image into 3 colours to make your life easier, something like this:

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("omr.jpg");

#Get image width / height
$w = ImageSX($im);
$h = ImageSY($im);

# Create a new output image
$out=imagecreate($w,$h);

# Allocate black, white and red
$black = imagecolorallocate($out,0,0,0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($out,255,255,255);
$red   = imagecolorallocate($out,255,0,0);

for($y=0;$y<$h;$y++){
   for($x=0;$x<$w;$x++){
      $rgb = imagecolorat($im,$x,$y);
      $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
      $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
      $b = $rgb & 0xFF;
      if($g>128){
         $colour=$white;
      } else if($r>128){
         $colour=$red;
      } else $colour=$black;
      imagesetpixel($out,$x,$y,$colour);
   }
}
imagepng($out,"result.png");
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks thanks thanks a loooooooot
It worked for me :D

Comment: can u please help me once more??

its my code

 
$file   = 'omr.jpg';
$degrees = 10;

$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($file) or notfound();

$rotate = imagerotate($source,$degrees,0xFFFFFF);

 
 imagejpeg($rotate,'199.jpg');

file_put_contents(imagejpeg($rotate) , $rotate);

imagedestroy($source);
imagedestroy($rotate);

and its working nice

bt in output page i am getting something like

"

ÿØÿàJFIFÿþ>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), default quality ÿajdlak;laskoAKXPOAD
Warning: file_put_contents(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource

I dont wnt to get this.

Comment: I'd be happy to help but, it's nearly impossible to read code in a comment block. Please just post it as a new question - questions are free :-) You'll also get a bigger audience and a better answer that way. If I don't see it, or no-one answers, just put a link to it here and I'll see it.

Comment: but they have forbid me to ask question saying "you have reached your question limit"
anyway thanks :)

Comment: When you send an image to a browser, you have to tell it first to expect an image using a *header* with `Content-type: image/jpeg`